# MacBook Air screen is too bright even on the lowest setting

Tags: ergonomics, brightness, macbook-air

Is there a tweak, hack, or piece of software that can adjust the brightness of the MacBook Air's screen below the settings that MacOS X allows by default?

In low light the lowest brightness setting is too bright for me (and the setting after that is black so that doesn't work at all).  :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [Flux](http://stereopsis.com/flux/) which helps me a lot at night. It gives you a somewhat lower brightness and the colors are adjusted according to the light you choose.